# targetting container class not type in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been struggling with a javascript charting script. To call the script, I have to place the following in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('table').visualize({type: 'line'});
    });
</script>
```

This script scrapes the table for data and then generates a pretty chart. All works fine, no problem. The problem is when I migrate it to the full website. I obviously have a number of tables on the page and this script attempts to scrape each and plce a chart immediately after. To combat this, I added a class to my target table of "charttable" and altered the above code to thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.charttable').visualize({type: 'line'});
    });
</script>
```

That now scrapes and generates the chart exactly where expected. The problem I now have is that the javascript it calls tries to draw and style the chart using various classes, which appear to be ignored, e.g. background colours all default to black, drawing of the x and y axis labels are all just placed on top of each other, etc. Example of javascript is below below

```
//function to create a chart
        var createChart = {
            pie: function(){    

                canvasContain.addClass('visualize-pie');

                if(o.pieLabelPos == 'outside'){ canvasContain.addClass('visualize-pie-outside'); }  

            var centerx = Math.round(canvas.width()/2);
                var centery = Math.round(canvas.height()/2);
                var radius = centery - o.pieMargin;             
            var counter = 0.0;
            var toRad = function(integer){ return    (Math.PI/180)*integer; };
            var labels = $('<ul class="visualize-labels"></ul>')
                .insertAfter(canvas);
```

each of these classes is styled by two style sheets, e.g.:

```
.visualize { margin: 60px 0 0 30px; padding: 70px 40px 90px; background: #222 url(../images/chartbg.png) top repeat-x; border: 1px solid #000; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; }
.visualize canvas { border: 1px solid #888; margin: -1px; background: #222; }
.visualize-labels-x, .visualize-labels-y { top: 70px; left: 40px; z-index: 100; }
```

I've tried adding .charttable in front of all the entries in the stylesheets, thinking it would allow me to target the class and subclass, but that didn't work.

I know that the script must be working at least partially correctly because it draws the chart with the headings and labels scraped from the table. It just won't draw the lines, correctly position the labels, or adhere to styling.

Was I write to add and target the class of "charttable" instead of just the container?
If no - is there another work around in terms of how I target the container?
If yes - why are the stylesheets now being ignored?

If the above makes no sense, I deeply apologies as I'm still learning Java...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its manipulating a variable "canvas" to create the chart, which you say is working.  It is adding the class to "canvasContainer" which you say is not working.  I would look further up in the code to determine how canvas and canvasContainer are defined.  Somewhere there is a break where canvasContainer is defined.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your feedback, I've actually traced it back to a CSS problem.One of my CSS elements has a display:none value that is being enforced on the chart. I'm currently trying to find a way to get my chart to ignore this by way of stopping the inheritance of the style sheet of the container.

Comment: hmm, that can't really be done.  If the parent is display:none, not much you can do.  I don't know the application, but you should find a way to make the chart and hidden element siblings in one container instead of the parent child relationship they currently have.